# Loop through multi-line string in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a wrapper for my jenkins jobs that will trigger (deploy service) the specific jobs from multi-line string. I'm able to list the jobs but I'm not able to build or run any command inside a groovt loop:

```
node {
 stage("stream") {
 try {
   for (i in stream.split("\\r?\\n")){
        build(job: "${i}", parameters: [string(name: 'ENVNAME', value: 'uat')])
   }   
 }       
 catch (Exception e) {
   println("ERR: Please check groups! " + e.getMessage());
  }
 }  
}
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
ERR: Please check groups! java.util.AbstractList$Itr
```

Even if I use directly the shell command

```
sh("knife ssh -x user 'chef_environment:uat AND recipe:${i}'' 'sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum; sleep 10;sudo chef-client -W -o ${i}'")
```

Echo the services works but any other command no. Do you have any suggestion or any other advice facing the fact that the jobs that will be triggered will be different each time/ each release.